# How does `alias sudo="sudo "` work?

Tags: shell, sh, alias, sudo

Looking at ways to pass current user's aliases to a `sudo` command, I found the following [on ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sudo#Passing_aliases):

> #### Passing aliases
>
> If you use a lot of aliases, you might have noticed that they do not
>   carry over to the root account when using sudo. However, there is an
>   easy way to make them work. Simply add the following to your
>   `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/bash.bashrc`:
>
> `alias sudo='sudo '`

I don't get why this works. If the shell does not care how many spaces are between two commands, how can this have any effect?

When manually adding a space, I see no difference:

```
$ alias e=echo
$ sudo e foo
sudo: e: command not found
$ sudo  e foo              # Manual space addition
sudo: e: command not found # Fail
$ alias sudo="sudo "       # Now with alias
$ sudo e foo
foo                        # Succeeds, but why?
```

Visibly aliasing sudo to sudo + space somehow allows passing aliases. This works on `zsh`, `bash` and `sh`, so it is not a shell-specific behavior.

### How does this alias work?

Comment: This is not something to understand, just don't do it.  Allowing sudo to invoke an alias is about as good an idea as standing on a rickety three legged stool with a noose around your neck.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, some elaboration on that would be interesting to hear ...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Looking at the man page for alias:

> A trailing space in VALUE causes the next word to be checked for
>       alias substitution when the alias is expanded.

Source: http://www.linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/aliash.html

Answer (score 2):

What we got in best practices for the team:

```
alias sodu='sudo'
alias sodo='sudo'
alias sdoo='sudo'
alias sudu='sudo'
alias sduo='sudo'
```

Just add an alias you think is necessary for yourself

Comment: i +1ed this because its funny and true

Answer (score 1):

The trailing space makes the shell try alias expansion on the next word as well.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37210013/2115619 for source.

This can be nested indefinitely:

```bash
alias e1=echo e2='echo ' b='extreme mega beans to the max'
e1 b
#> b
e2 b
#> extreme mega beans to the max
e2 e2 e2 b
#> echo echo extreme mega beans to the max
e2 e2 e1 b
#> echo echo b
e2 e1 e2 b
#> echo e2 b
e1 e2 e2 b
#> e2 e2 b
```

You can also make a useless but transparent alias like this:

```bash
alias echo='echo ' expand=' '
echo expand expand expand expand expand expand expand expand expand meow
#> meow
```