# zsh alias completion (trailing space) breaks with functions

Tags: bash, zsh

When you create an [alias with a trailing space](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37209913/519360) like `alias sudo='sudo '`, it instructs zsh or bash to traverse the next argument for an alias, so if you also have `alias aup='apt update'`, you could say `sudo aup` and it'll run `apt update` as root.

This does not, however, work when you have a function. For example:

```sh
_installer_helper() {
  local RETVAL
  command "$@"
  RETVAL="$?"
  hash -r
  return "$RETVAL"
}

alias apt='_installer_helper apt'

# (zsh only) this ensures apt subcommands still complete correctly
setopt complete_aliases

alias sudo='sudo '
```

Not what I want:

```
$ sudo apt update
sudo: _installer_helper: command not found
$
```

How do I get this to work properly in both bash and zsh? (Yes, the `setopt` command is only run by zsh.)

Comment: It seems to be working properly to me. The `apt` alias was expanded to `_installer_helper apt` and `sudo` knows nothing of shell functions, so it complained. What behaviour were you expecting?

Comment: @muru – I was hoping to be able to pass the function the same way an alias is passed. Perhaps that's too large an ask of the shell.